# Tying HTML PHP PDO together

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I am very new to this and this is my first post to stackoverflow.
I am simply trying to:
Create a dropdown list that
1) Triggers a query (Gettech.php) everytime it changes
2) Updates another field with the results of the query

In this case they select a "tech name" and it should update another field with the associated "tech number" (result of the PDO query) everytime "tech name" changes.  This is what I have:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="Gettech.php" method="get">
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
       <label for="name"> Name:</label>
       <select class= "form-control" id="techname" name=techname><option value="">Select...</option>
       <option value="First Name">First Name</option>
       <option value="Second Name">Second Name</option>                       .
        .
        .
       </select>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the Gettech.php part

```js
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "####";
$password = "####";
$name = "Joey";
try {
     $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=staff', $username, $password);
 } catch (PDOException $e) {
 echo $e->getMessage()."<br>";
    die();
 }
$sql = "SELECT name, techid from techs where name= '$name'";
foreach( $db->query($sql) as $row ) {
echo $row['name']."<br>".$row['techid']."<br>";
         }
$db = null;
?>
```

Individually they work but don't know how to tie them together into a working solution.  Hints are welcome!

Comment: Check again your SQL query

Comment: What makes you think that the given query is valid? You should definitly check for SQL errors through `$db->errorInfo()`

Comment: PHP noob and Nico- In trying to cleanup the query for the post, I eliminated too much ...there is a value the the "where name=".  when complete it works on its own.  I am trying to bring the name selected in the form into the query and display results into a second field.on the form.  Thank you for responding.

Comment: Can you edit your post to make it complete, please ?

Comment: KBell - Sorry I took so long had to figure out how to edit the post :)

Comment: No problem. And for your information, you can notify people in comments with "@" character this way : @PHPnoob

Comment: @KBell thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description of what you are trying to do, you really need to do this with Javascript/JQuery. I have not tested this code but just hoping to get you on the right path.
Please visit https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods to learn about AJAX.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
    <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
          <script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                   <label for="name"> Name:</label>
                   <select class="form-control" id="techname" name=techname>
                   <option value="">Select...</option>
                   <option value="First Name">First Name</option>
                   <option value="Second Name">Second Name</option>
                    .
                    .
                   </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div id="content"> <!-- AJAX DATA --> </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "####";
$password = "####";
$name = "Joey";
try {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=staff', $username, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error = [
        'status' => "error",
        'error'  => $e->getMessage()
    ];

    return json_encode($error);
}

// Sanitize and validate this for security & integrity purposes
if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
    $name = $_GET['name'];
} else {
    $error = [
        'status' => "error",
        'error'  => "$_GET not received"
    ];

    return json_encode($error);
}

$sql = "SELECT name, techid FROM techs WHERE name = :name";
// Make sure you are using prepared statements, 
// it's one of the most powerful security features of PDO
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

// You need to "fetch" the result before you can use it
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

$db = null;

foreach($result as $key => $row) {
    $html .= "<div>{$row['name']}</div>";
    $html .= "<div>{$row['techid']}</div>";
}

$data = [
            'status' => "success",
            'html'   => $html
        ];

return json_encode($data);
?>
```

ajax.js

```
// Wait for DOM to be ready
$(function() {
    $('#techname').on('change', function(e) {

        // Prevents page from reloading
        e.preventDefault();

        var value = $("option:selected", this).val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            // If file is not in docroot, you need to specify the subdirectory
            url: "Gettech.php",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: value.serialize(),
            beforeSend: function() {
                // Good idea to put a loader here so the user knows 
                // something is happening if request takes time
                $('.loading').fadeIn('fast');
            },
            success: function(result) {

                if (result.status === "error") {
                    var data = result.error;
                } else if (result.status === "success") {
                    var data = result.html;
                }

                // Hide the loader once completed
                $('.loading').fadeOut('fast');

                // Add query data to the DOM
                $('#content').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This is far more then I could have asked for and very much appreciated.  Second time Ajax was mentioned so I will be looking at that aggressively.  I will post the final results once completed.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Also, I found a missing `</div>` in your HTML, please note my update.